# Cannot bind to the prorperty or column Return on the DataSource Parameter name:dataMember C#

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I am trying to access the voltage dictionary to get the key value pair , and according to key value I am trying to Bind the Voltage Label text property with the Voltage dictionary's value , but it throws an exception that Cannot bind to the prorperty or column Return on the DataSource Parameter name:dataMember.
please find my code as per below:
`public ZoneValue(Dictionary<string, double> voltages,string key)
{
InitializeComponent();

```
    ValueLabel.DataBindings.Add("Text", voltages, key);// issue is here
    KeyLabel.Text = key;
    ValueLabel.Left = (this.Width / 2) - (ValueLabel.Width / 2);
    KeyLabel.Left = (this.Width / 2) - (KeyLabel.Width / 2);
}`
```

I want to get the value of the Key from the voltage Dictionary and change the Text property of the ValueLabel

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason to use that approach? you could just make the next:

```
        var value = voltages[key];
        //ValueLabel.DataBindings.Add("Text", voltages, key);// issue is here
        ValueLabel.Text = value.ToString();
        KeyLabel.Text = key;
        ValueLabel.Left = (this.Width / 2) - (ValueLabel.Width / 2);
        KeyLabel.Left = (this.Width / 2) - (KeyLabel.Width / 2);
```

Comment: because voltage is my Live voltage, and it is going to change frequently so, i want to Update my VoltageLabel with the Live Voltage.

Answer (score 0):

Using WinForms, I want to bind a label's Text property to the value of a particular entry in a `Dictionary<string, double>`.

you can bind your label's Text property to an item of a dictionary by using the following code:

```
label1.DataBindings.Add("Text", dictionary["key"], "");
```

where dictionary is the name of your `Dictionary<string, double>` and key is the particular entry you want to bind to.